# Apache FastCGI app fails to find suitable libfcgi (Mac OS 10.8.4)

Tags: c++, apache, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I'm trying to make an experimental FastCGI app and I keep getting a certain error.

I've compiled all the binaries and libs except apache (shipped with Mac) on the machine.

The error is as follows:

```
[Thu Jul 25 20:40:34 2013] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/tiny-cgi.fcgi" started (pid 49396)
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/fasihrana/Documents/apparicion/fcgi-dev/lib/libfcgi.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/tiny-cgi.fcgi
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/fasihrana/Documents/apparicion/fcgi-dev/lib/libfcgi.0.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
[Thu Jul 25 20:40:34 2013] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/tiny-cgi.fcgi" (pid 49396) terminated due to uncaught signal '5' (Trace/BPT trap)
[Thu Jul 25 20:40:34 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 49398 for worker proxy:reverse
[Thu Jul 25 20:40:34 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1837): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
```

and then the following:

```
[Thu Jul 25 20:41:07 2013] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/tiny-cgi.fcgi" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
[Thu Jul 25 20:41:07 2013] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/tiny-cgi.fcgi" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (30 sec)
[Thu Jul 25 20:41:07 2013] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/tiny-cgi.fcgi"
```

I keep thinking its the compilation of the mod_fastcgi vs. the compilation of fastcgi app, but the 'file' command reveals the following:

```
$ file tiny-cgi.fcgi 
tiny-cgi.fcgi: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ file mod_fastcgi.so 
mod_fastcgi.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64

# file /usr/sbin/httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ file libfcgi.0.dylib 
libfcgi.0.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I got the configuration and tutorial from http://spointeau.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/fastcgi-with-apache-on-mac-os-x-lion.html maybe I'm missing something else in the configuration.

I'm running out of ideas, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using fastcgi-devkit 2.4.1 which isn't stable or in a working condition. Installed 2.4.0 vis homebrew and it worked like a charm.